# What does "declaration is incompatible" error mean in VS Code with C_lang linting?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, lint

I'm writing a simple code in C language, and this works.
Which compiles and excutes with no errors, gives the expected output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  struct SiteTemplate {
    int views;
  };
  
  int visit(struct SiteTemplate *site) {
    site -> views++;
    return 0;
  }

  struct SiteTemplate site;
  site.views = 0;

  visit(&site);
  printf("%d\n", site.views);

  return 0;
}
```

But in my VS Code, with C_Cpp linting is on, my IDE shows the following error and other problems with it.

```
declaration is incompatible with previous "visit" (declared at line 8)
```

Having a screenshot of it:

[image: VS Code Screenshot]

This error linting is really confusing me since my code works with `gcc`, it doesn't show any error when compiling.

And also, if I move my *struct* and *function* definition to the global level instead of inside `main()`, then the errors don't exist anymore... But what's the error `declaration is incompatible`? Or is there any problem with my code?

> [Click here to view the another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEl5u.png) to save whitespaces of this page.
>
> By the way, the version of my VS Code is **1.52.0**, with default C_Cpp linting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested function definition is not standard C, it's supported by compiler extensions. According to C standard, any function definition needs to appear outside of any other function definition.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. So `incompatible` in the error message means the syntax of code isn't compatible to C standard, is that correct?

Comment: @CasimirCrystal No, it just means compiler cannot verify the signature of `visit` properly. given that this is a non-standard thing, compilers are not bound to support this nested definition and might be doing funky things. Stick to the standards,